# why a new window is created when I add a tab to a tabwidget from a child class in PYQT?

Tags: inheritance, pyqt

I've a PYQT5 GUI with a tabwidget where I need to dynamically add/remove tabs. this main GUI is created with QTDesigner. The new tab must load an other *.ui designed as well with QTDesigner.

This is working perfectly when creating the new tab from the MainUI class:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
import sys


class MainUi(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainUi, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('main.ui', self) # load main_ui GUI
        self.show()
        self.sessions = []

    def tabWidget_Main_AddSession(self):
        self.sessions.append(Session())
        self.tabWidget_Main.addTab(uic.loadUi('session.ui'), 'title') # Create a new tab with session.ui inside


class Session():
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #... do whatever here


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = MainUi()
    ui.tabWidget_Main_AddSession()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My application is growing and I need to organize my files. So basically I try to push some of the methods from the MainUi class to some other files through new classes.
Now I wish to create the new tab from an other class that will be in an other file later on.
In order that the class I'm calling to create the new tab I need it to know about the widgets used in the MainUi so I tried to have my child class to know about the parent class. And this works, BUT my application creates two differents windows. The fisrt one before the new tab creation, and a second window with the everything + the new tab...

I'm guessing this is a problem of inheritance but any clue what I'm doing wrong ?

Here is the code :

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
import sys


class MainUi(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainUi, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('main.ui', self) # load main GUI
        self.show()
        self.sessions = []

    def tabWidget_Main_AddSession(self):
        self.sessions.append(Session())
        self.sessions[-1].add_tab() # Create a new tab


class Session(MainUi):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Session, self).__init__()
        self.page = uic.loadUi('session.ui')

    def add_tab(self):
        self.tabWidget_Main.addTab(self.page, 'title') # create the tab loading a *.ui


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = MainUi()
    ui.tabWidget_Main_AddSession()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks
Stephane

Comment: Why are you trying to subclass `MainUi`? If you're doing this to "know about the parent class", that's not exactly what is happening: if we use the *proper* terms, what you really want to to is to make the **instance** of the child know about the **instance** of the parent. But since you're using inheritance, the reality is that your child knows about a ***new*** instance, the one it inherits from, which is obviously useless. The point is that the original situation was still the correct one: it should be the responsibility of the parent to do something on a child, not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
This means it should be preferable to have inside the MainUI class all the methods doing anything on any part of the GUI ? So that everything related to the GUI shall be in MainUi ??? This will be huge

Comment: No, I never said that. The metaphor is actually quite right: a "parent" should only be responsible of its "children", but grandparents *could* be also responsible of their grandchildren, if it's their responsibility. The "main" window should not do everything (just like a parent should never do everything for their children), but if their children's action concerns them, they should take care of it. In your case: your child widget is being added to *another* child of the parent (MainUi), and since that parent *is* concerned about that (a possible size change) it should take care of that.

Comment: ok I get it but how the childs should communicate with the parent without using inheritance then ?

Comment: The standard Qt way: [signals](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html).

Comment: going to investigate on this. Thanks!